# What time is it?

Tags: riddle, language

**Bon Giorno!**

- 5 20 14 5 4 14 5 16
- 15 9 26 9 14 9
- 1 3 9 20 1 13 5 20 1 13

**What time is it!?**

Comment: Kind of a long shot, does it somehow refers to ROT13(Gur yrnavat gbjre bs Cvfn)?

Comment: I don't want to give away clues yet and say yes or no. But i will later if noone is able to solve it. So to answer your question... maybe, maybe not ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It can be very early morning 01:12, if the word "pendente" refers to the leaning tower of Pisa which subsequently refers to the Fibonacci series (Pisano). You might want us to "initialize" his sequence.

From the three Italian words already discovered by @hexomino I was trying to find associated words/phrases that give "convergent" instructions that allows us to approach one unique concept.

Pendente->"it is time to", "leaning"
Inizio->        "ab origino", "from the beginning"
Matematica-> ...

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer and reasoning, well done :)

Comment: How do all three words work together here, and what's the connection between the first word and the building you mention?

Comment: @tmpearce I think the explanation might be: ROT13 ("Gbeer CRAQRAGR" vf ubj Vgnyvna pnyy gur Yrnavat Gbjre bs Cvfn, naq sebz gurer gur pbaarpgvba gb Svobanppv (jub jnf sebz Cvfn). ZNGRZNGVPN (Zngu) cbvagf gb gur snzbhf Svobanppv Frdhrapr naq VAVMVB (Fgneg) vaqvpngrf gb pbafvqre gur svefg ahzoref bs gur frdhrapr.)

Comment: @Edivad Well explained! And yes, obviously you were on to it first, so good job :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Takes some abstract connections to get there!

Answer (score 8):

I think it is

> Time to start Maths

Reasoning

> Translating each of the number sequences into letters (using A=1, B=2, etc), we have
>  ETNEDNEP
>  OIZINI
>  ACITAMETAM
>  Spelling these backwards and appending gives PENDENTE INIZIO MATEMATICA which looks like Italian.
>  Unfortunately my Italian is not good but Google translate says it is "Pending Early Math" or perhaps "Pending Start to Maths".

Comment: I wasn't sure how to make that last step, but I think this is it.

Comment: You are right about the words! But your answer is not correct!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Perhaps I've misordered the words? I really don't know Italian sentence structure.

Comment: Hmm, don't know how to say this without giving away a hint. But just try to somehow make sense of the three words :)

Comment: I'm not going any further with this, but I do see the beginnings of rot13(CRZQNF) in your reasoning. Maybe? I don't know where to go after that.

Comment: No, no such thing in my reasoning!

Answer (score 1):

> @hexomino confirmed in their answer this is using A1Z26
>
>   Based on that, we could read "What time is **X**?" where **X** is also in A1Z26
>
>   If we decipher **it** we get **920** so it is 9:20

Comment: This is not the correct answer. You have to somehow make sense of the three words  to get the correct answer :)